# Generate metatype descriptions with maven-scr-plugin and OSGI R6 annotations

Tags: osgi, maven-bundle-plugin, maven-scr-plugin

I am using maven-scr-plugin to generate component and metatype descriptions. I am migrating from org.apache.felix.scr annotations to org.osgi.service.component annotations.

Carsten Ziegeler has written an excellent blog on how to do this migration [here](http://blog.osoco.de/2016/05/migrating-from-the-apache-felix-scr-annotations-to-the-osgi-declarative-services-annotations/). However, that does not explain on how to have the metatype descriptions directly generated from the component annotations. Instead, I would have to make a separate configuration @interface for every component, and rewrite all component activators (at least, to make use of the added value of those extra @interface classes).

I can still use the maven-scr-plugin to process the osgi annotations by adding a dependency on `org.apache.felix.scr.ds-annotations`. However, maven-scr-plugin only outputs metatype information if that is explicitly switched on. With the felix annotations, a dedicated parameter `metatype=true` in the `@Component` annotation is available to enable metatype generation. However, such a parameter is not available in the OSGi version of the `@Component` annotation.

Is there a way to either force maven-scr-plugin to generate the metatype descriptions, or can I make maven-bundle-plugin (or bndtools) to generate the metatype data based on the osgi @Component annotation, instead of having to define a dedicated configuration class for every component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Metatype is generated when you use the `@Designate` annotation. (At least in the bnd implementation.)

```
 @Designate( ocd=Config.class, factory=true )
 @Component
 public class SomeComponent {
    @ObjectClassDefinition
    @interface Config {
       int port();
    }
    @Activate
    void activate( Config config) { }
 }
```

Comment: Yes, I understood, and this works without problems. However, to do this properly, I would also have to change all activators, as demonstrated in your example (I know it can be done without, but that leaves a lot of unused boilerplate code in my classes). Can I see your answer as a confirmation that bnd does not support the approach I am looking for? Then I can exclude that solution path, only leaving the maven-scr-plugin as a possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you need a separate configuration @interface for each component. It is also not possible to generate the meta type from the @Component annotations as they do not describe configurations.

Comment: The @Component annotation has the `property` parameter, where all basic info for the configuration parameters is defined (name, default value, object type). Of course, additional information like limiting ranges and explenatory descriptions cannot be added, but I do not need those in my case

Comment: I don't think the properties on @Component are taken into account when creating the meta type but I might be wrong. Maybe Peter can answer that.

Comment: They are not. Metatype xml is generated from ObjectClassDefinition annotated types. It is not generated from property elements of Component annotations.